# Reproduce subset of bibliography in document

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have documented with references at the end. I would like to reproduce an entry of the bibliography in the text, with the corrected key (e.g. the reference number) and in whatever style I choose.

I use bibtex. Can you provide a minimal working example for such a construction?

Comment: Would you consider using `biblatex`? It has a `\fullcite` command, which reproduces the corresponding item in the references section.

Comment: @Bernard: No, I have not. I have clue how to switch from standard bibtex to biblatex.